# How to route to api/values?id=1&type=2

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working with .net core 2.1 web api. I have a ValuesController and routes such as api/values/5 & api/values/ work fine. But now I would like to route to something like api/values?id=5&type=2. Is it possible to have a route like this?

I have searched stackoverflow and other sites but haven't found a way to do this. I tried with the code below, but doesn't work.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value" + id;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id, int type)
        {
            return "value: " + id + "with type: " + type;
        }
    }
```

I would like to route as api/values?id=5&type=2 or api/values/id=5&type=2

Answer (score 0):

You can't difference a route by a query string. You should merge the two 'Get' methods and call to `api/values?id=5&type=2`

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(int id, int type)
{

    if (id == 0 && type == 0)
    {
        return Ok(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok("value: " + id + " with type: " + type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("id={id}&type={type}")]   // GET api/values/id=5&type=2
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id, int type)
    {
        return "value: " + id + "with type: " + type;
    }
```